# "How like you" in speech

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

What's this structure and is it common to speak like that?

- I got into trouble yesterday, again.
- How like you.

Comment: That's not exactly common, but it is in use. *That's just like you* would probably be more common.

Comment: Do you also want to know the meaning, or just what it's called? It's not something you would hear all the time, but it's not unheard of either. In addition to @Davo's comment you could also say "That's so/very like you."

Comment: I understand the meaning, I'm more interested in the structer.

Comment: What @Davo said. By the same token, it's less common (and *very* slightly poetic / affected / twee) to exclaim ***How odd!*** in contexts where most of us would say ***That's odd!***.

Comment: On the other hand, **How nice!** or **How wonderful!** seem fairly common (IMO).

Comment: @stangdon But here it doesn't carry this meaning!

Comment: @SovereignSun - sorry, which meaning are you referring to?

Comment: @stangdon it's definitely what SteveES commented, ""That's so/very like you.""

Comment: @SovereignSun - Those two statements aren't that different.  "How like you" and "That is very like you" mean almost exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this sentence, [**how** is being used with the meaning of "to what degree or amount"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/how).  We often use this in questions, like "How strong are they?" but it can also be used in exclamations when we want to call attention to the degree of something, like ["How cold it was!"](https://books.google.com/books?id=V01-76iQ48gC&lpg=PA934&dq=%22How%20cold%20it%20was!%22&pg=PA934#v=onepage&q=%22How%20cold%20it%20was!%22&f=false)  In this context, it means something like "Note the degree of (whatever it is)."

[**Like** here is a preposition meaning "similar to", 'in the manner of", or "has the characteristics of".](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like)

So the meaning of the entire sentence is essentially, "Note how characteristic of you that is", or, more fluently, "That is very characteristic of you."